# tableview delete row swift

Tags: swift, tableview, delete-row

I'm fairly new to swift code, and I'm having trouble deleting a row/event from the table view after I created them, everything works fine but when I click on delete I get an error which terminates the app, this is the code bellow

```swift
import UIKit

var selectedDate = Date()

class WeeklyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,
                            UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var event = Event()
    var totalSquares = [Date]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setCellsView()
        setWeekView()
    }
    
    func setCellsView()
    {
        let width = (collectionView.frame.size.width - 2) / 7
        let height = (collectionView.frame.size.height - 2)
        
        let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
    
    func setWeekView()
    {
        totalSquares.removeAll()
        
        var current = CalendarHelper().sundayForDate(date: selectedDate)
        let nextSunday = CalendarHelper().addDays(date: current, days: 7)
        
        while (current < nextSunday)
        {
            totalSquares.append(current)
            current = CalendarHelper().addDays(date: current, days: 1)
        }
        
        monthLabel.text = CalendarHelper().monthString(date: selectedDate)
            + " " + CalendarHelper().yearString(date: selectedDate)
        collectionView.reloadData()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        totalSquares.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "calCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCell
        
        let date = totalSquares[indexPath.item]
        cell.dayOfMonth.text = String(CalendarHelper().dayOfMonth(date: date))
        
        if(date == selectedDate)
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        }
        else
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        selectedDate = totalSquares[indexPath.item]
        collectionView.reloadData()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func previousWeek(_ sender: Any)
    {
        selectedDate = CalendarHelper().addDays(date: selectedDate, days: -7)
        setWeekView()
    }
    
    @IBAction func nextWeek(_ sender: Any)
    {
        selectedDate = CalendarHelper().addDays(date: selectedDate, days: 7)
        setWeekView()
    }
    
    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool
    {
        return false
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return Event().eventsForDate(date: selectedDate).count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID") as! EventCell
        event = Event().eventsForDate(date: selectedDate)[indexPath.row]
        cell.eventLabel.text = event.name + " " + CalendarHelper().timeString(date: event.date)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if editingStyle == .delete{
            self.event.name.removeFirst()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```swift
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). Table view: <UITableView:
```

I'm pretty sure the error is probably at the tableview func, because the

```swift
if editingStyle == .delete{
            self.event.name.removeFirst() //This line is the problem
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the datasource length is wrong after you called deleteRows(at:with:).

This is the number of rows in your datasource

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return Event().eventsForDate(date: selectedDate).count
    }
```

And when you are updating your tableview, you should update the same datasource, but you use

```
self.event.name.removeFirst()
```

They are clearly not the same datasource

Try to use a global attribute to store the datasource, I see that you are instantiating Event() everywhere, which is wrong.